# Thesaurus Completion Error in GVim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, thesaurus

I am using GVim on Windows. I am trying to use Thesaurus completion using `Ctrl + x + Ctrl + t`. But it gives me the following error.

[image]

I have added the thesaurus file path in my `_vimrc` file.

[image]

And the mthesaur.txt is available at that location.

BTW, The insert mode completions such as keyword completion (`Ctrl + x + Ctrl + n`) and file completion (`ctrl + x + ctrl + f`) work fine.

I want to avoid using any Vim plugins for this inbuilt functionality.

Comment: When you say `in my _VIMRC file`, do you mean `C:\Users\username\_vimrc` (note the capitalization)?

Comment: Yes. I meant `_vimrc`. It is at the right location. I have tons of customizations and plugins in my vimrc file, which works. So, reading from `_vimrc` is not an issue. Thanks.

Comment: While running vim, what is the output of ":verbose set thesaurus"?  Maybe it's getting overridden after you set it in your config.

Comment: @RandyMorris, it says `thesaurus=c:/users/myusername/mthesaur.txt   Last set from ~\_vimrc`. So it looks right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Windows pathing with backslashes, like this:

`set thesaurus+=C:\my\user\mthesaurus.txt`

This answer was actually mentioned in the comments...

Comment: I should apologize to the previous answer'ers. I had `  set wildignore+=*.txt` in the VIMRC that is the reason why the thesaurus text file was ignored. I removed it and it worked. Thank you for resurrecting this post.